# App crashes after dialogFragment.onDismiss called, Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dialogfragment

So I'm trying to call a dialogFragment, it works perfectly until I call the onDismiss function from the activity to make an action...

I got a dialog fragment in the hangman game which says if you won or loose, there is a button in the dialog which says if "try again" or "next word", in case you won or loose,
it looks like this:
[image: lose dialog] [image: won dialog]

When the client clicks one of these buttons the dialog will disappear and a new word should appear and reset everything except the word if won...
So I've tried to set onDismiss listener to the dialogFragment inside the activity where the current game is running, but instead of setting dismiss listener, the app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: WonDialogFragment{db6bbec}
```

here is the code where I call the dialogFragment:

```
// in case the user won
if (isWon) {
// Disable all the buttons immediately.
setEnabledToEachButton(false);
// check if there is already a dialog.
if (!dialogFragment.isAdded() && !dialogFragment.isVisible()) {
// show the dialog
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), WonDialogFragment.WON_TAG);
dialogFragment.onDismiss(new DialogInterface() {
               @Override
               public void cancel() {

               }

               @Override
               public void dismiss() {
                      currentIndex++;
                      nextWordOrTryAgain();
                      updateTextView();
               }
         });
}
}
```

if I should provide more information to solve my problem let me know...
thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by calling onDismiss?

Comment: When the dialog being dismissed I want to do some operations, like clearing the TextViews...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onDismiss is a lifecycle method of DialogFragment. You are not supposed to call it.
You have 2 options,

**Try to use the [OnDismissListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener):**

```
dialogFragment.getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        currentIndex++;
        nextWordOrTryAgain();
        updateTextView();
    }
}
```

**Or to Create a custom listener interface:**

```
public interface DialogDismissed {
    void onDialogDismissed();
}
```

Inside you dialog, have a setter and keep the listener interface:

```
public void setListener(DialogDismissed listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

When you call **dismiss()** inside you dialog use:

```
if (mListener != null) {
    mListener.onDialogDismissed()
}
```

And when creating the Dialog, set the listener:

```
dialogFragment.setListener(new DialogDismissed {
    @Override
    void onDialogDismissed() {
        currentIndex++;
        nextWordOrTryAgain();
        updateTextView();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried these methods, but none of them seems to work for me

Comment: Do you call dismiss() inside your dialog fragment?

Comment: No, I call it from activity...
(off the record are you Israeli? your name is גיורא ורד and it's an Israeli name :) )

Comment: Yep Israeli. If you call it from the activity, why do you need a dismissal callback? Why not do atuff after you call dismiss?

Comment: I do want to call it after the dialog has been dismissed, but I want to change things inside the activity, if you know a better approach let me know... or maybe I should use alertDialog or something like that...

Comment: I don't know your end-goal.. Why not changing the Activity after calling dimiss()? Do you need some info from the DialogFragment?

Comment: No, I do not want any information from the dialog, just to know when it was dismissed and then to make some operations in the activity... 
אני אסביר גם בעברית אם זה מותר... בכל מקרה אחרי שהדיאלוג הופיע, וסגרו אותו אני רוצה לעשות כל מיני דברים באקטיביטי, כגון לעשות ריסט לכל הדברים שלי שם... מה ששלחת פשוט נותן לי את אותם שגיאות כמו שהיה מקודם :(

Comment: Keep it in English. Add more of your code so I can better understand what it is you are trying ti do..

Comment: I edited the question. thank you very much for your time I really appreciate this! I'll give you an upvote even though it didn't work for me :( maybe in the future it will help someone

Comment: Anyways, calling onDismiss is the wrong way. If you can add the code of the dismiss call and what the nextWordOrTryAgain and uodateTextView are doing I can try to help.